# Check if cell is blank, then show the value of adjacent cell in userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba

First time posting here.

I need some help!

So I am trying to create a loop upon initialization of user form. Basically when I click the user form, the text box on top will show the name of the person with a blank adjacent cell

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With wb
    
    i = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) = False

        'Check if cell i, 2 is blank (in this case Range B2 is blank so code will proceed)

        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) = True Then
    
            'Get value of adjacent cell and place in text box
            Textbox1.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
            'value is name of person with blank adjacent cell value

        End If
    
        i = i + 1
        

    Loop

    'code will loop until there is no longer any blanks in column B
    End With
End Sub
```

### Range B2 is blank

[image: Range B2 is blank]

### Range A2 should be value of text box

[image: Range A2 should be value of text box]

Comment: your on the right track, just keep iterating the control variables until you hit a cell with a value.

Comment: Hi! I get the "overflow" error :(

Comment: Hello. Just some pointers: There is no real utility in using `Integer`s, you should use `Long` most of the time. Since `i` and `j` are always the same value, why use two variables? You should also always be explicit in Sheets and Cells references, here `IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value)` calls are using the default active sheet of the current active workbook, that can be or not the one you expect, while `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1)` specify the sheet. So the two cells might in fact be in different sheets.

Comment: Hi! I revised the code using the changes you mentioned (please check above). I tested it, but still no luck... it runs momentarily then error 1004 appears.

Comment: According to your posted image, what should the text box show after exiting the sub? Is this happening in one worksheet? At this moment, it will show `Name1, Name2, Name3...` until it hits a value n column `B` which makes no sense because it is too fast and you won't see these values, you will only see the last value before it hits the `B` column value. If there is no value in column B, an error will occur.

Comment: Hello! The text box should show "Name1" if the adjacent cell (in this case Range B2) is blank. Yes this is happening only in one worksheet. 

For example:
If there is a value in Range B2, then the code will loop and check Range B3 if it is blank. If range B3 is blank, then the text box will show "Name2" the adjacent cell in the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Do...Loop

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long: i = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    TextBox1.Value = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value

End Sub
```

Here are some other flavors doing the same:

```
Sub DoLoop2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long: i = 2

    Do
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then Exit Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    TextBox1.Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

End Sub

Sub DoLoop3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long: i = 2

    Do
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
            TextBox1.Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thread can now be closed! Thank you everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this code using for loop

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set mysheet = ActiveSheet
'find the last row number of a range using Find Function
  LastRow = mysheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Cells(i, 1).Value ' add person's name to textbox1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```